# Oracle Query for fetching previously updated record

Tags: oracle

Oracle query on to get changed details with what changed previously,
say Value X was updated WITH value Y and now I need help to form a query to fetch previous record that is X

Comment: Unless you are storing the previous value in another column/table... you can't. Once a row has been updated, the previous value of that row is gone.

Comment: You can make use of Table Triggers to store the state of your records prior to Update in a corresponding history table.  When the trigger detects a change in the values of certain fields you can design the trigger to then copy the existing state of the record into your history table.  This is how an Audit table works basically.  This allows you to also keep track of ALL changes and by whom/when those changes were made.  This can play a big part with security.

Answer (score 0):

In the event you DO need to keep track of certain record states based on the data contained in the fields within said records within your database, Triggers will allow you to move the records prior to them being UPDATED or DELETED into a corresponding History Table or otherwise known as an Audit table. The idea is you would then query your Audit table based on the date/time you suspect the record having been updated to retrieve the value of the field prior to that field being updated.

**An example UPDATE/DELETE Trigger**

```
TRIGGER user_schema.ACCOUNTS_HIST_TRIG
  AFTER
   DELETE OR UPDATE of account_bus_id, account_name, account_phone, other_field_you_care_about
  ON user_schema.accounts
 REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
  FOR EACH ROW

 DECLARE

   numUser number; /* Used to store user_id */   

 BEGIN

  /* Perhaps you have code to pull in the user that performed the update */
  numuser := user_schema.get_user_updated();

  INSERT INTO user_schema.accounts_hist(
    account_id,
    account_type,
    account_phone,
    account_phone_type,
    updated_by
  )
  VALUES(:OLD.account_id,
    :OLD.account_type,
    :OLD.account_phone,
    :OLD.account_phone_type,
    numuser);

exception
   WHEN others THEN
     RAISE;
 END;
```